# 4 bit adder using VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to implement 4 bit full adder using VHDL code. I used for loop for the carry in to propagate to the next adder. But Sum gives undefined(U) values in testbench. Help me to reach out the problem

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity adder_4bit is
Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
Sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
end adder_4bit;

architecture Behavioral of adder_4bit is
signal carry : STD_LOGIC := Cin;
begin

process(A,B,Cin)
variable carry : STD_LOGIC := Cin;
begin
for i in 0 to 3 loop
Sum(i) \<= A(i) xor B(i) xor carry;  
carry := (A(i) and B(i)) or (B(i) and carry) or (carry and A(i));
end loop;
Cout \<= carry;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you should assign a value to the variable `carry` inside the process. Setting the default value at variable declaration is not enough. By assigning the variable inside the process, it's value changes every time to the value of `Cin` when the vector `Sum` is reevaluated based on the change of any of the signals inside the process sensitivity list.
The reason why you were receiving `Sum` as an undefined U, is because the first evaluation of bit 0 of vector `Sum` when `i = 0` was seeing a value of `carry = 'U'` since you did not assign a value to `carry` before the line `Sum(i) <= A(i) xor B(i) xor carry;`. If you change the radix of the signal `Sum` in your simulation, only the value of bit 0 of vector `Sum` is 'U', the rest should depend on the value of `A` and `B` vectors.
The below code should solve your issue.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity adder_4bit is
  Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    B    : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    Cin  : in  STD_LOGIC;
    Sum  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
end adder_4bit;

architecture Behavioral of adder_4bit is
--I would remove this signal. It is not used.  
--signal carry : STD_LOGIC := Cin;
begin

  process(A,B,Cin)
    variable carry : STD_LOGIC := Cin;
  begin
    carry := Cin; -- assign value to the variable inside the process
    for i in 0 to 3 loop
      Sum(i) <= A(i) xor B(i) xor carry;
      carry  := (A(i) and B(i)) or (B(i) and carry) or (carry and A(i));
    end loop;
    Cout <= carry;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```